# Content not showing in CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Toolbar in Activity but when i try to run app after implementing Toolbar with

```
DrawerLayout >> CoordinatorLayout >> AppBarLayout
```

Content not showing. Here is layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="#FFECECEC"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        android:background="#FFECECEC"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="Timer : "
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtquesnum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1/10"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@xml/togglecheck"
            android:checked="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/seperator" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taque"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="Question"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:typeface="normal" />
                <com.applidium.shutterbug.FetchableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/splash_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/normal"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taOpt5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="0"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:hint="Option 1"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/normal"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taOpt6"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:hint="Option 2"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/normal"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taOpt7"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:hint="Option 3"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/normal"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taOpt8"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:hint="Option 4"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But when I move content inside AppBarLayout so everything is visible but inside appbar. how to fix this issue? Any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using Cordinator layout your layout should look like this

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
<AppBarLayout>
   //Toolbar and other contents should come here
</AppBarLayout>

<Recycler Or Nested Scroll View>

<LinearLayout
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

 //This is used when you have a collapsing toolbar and you need to add a scrolling behaviour for your views.

<LinearLayout/>

<Recycler Or Nested Scroll View/>
```

Instead try this layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:background="#FFECECEC"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:text="Timer : "
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtquesnum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1/10"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@xml/togglecheck"
                android:checked="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/seperator" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/taque"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:text="Question"
                        android:textColor="@color/Black"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:typeface="normal" />
                    <com.applidium.shutterbug.FetchableImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/splash_icon" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/normal"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/taOpt5"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_span="0"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:hint="Option 1"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/Black"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/normal"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/taOpt6"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:hint="Option 2"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/Black"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/normal"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/taOpt7"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:hint="Option 3"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/Black"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/normal"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/taOpt8"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:hint="Option 4"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/Black"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I try changing layout height with match_parent but hotchpotch everything.

Comment: I already try this method sir its working but everything run under AppBarLayout

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center" >
```

**to**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center" >
```

**Just change the height `android:layout_height="match_parent"`**

All code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="#FFECECEC"
                                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                    android:scrollbars="none"
                                    tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFECECEC">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="Timer : "
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtquesnum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1/10"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@xml/togglecheck"
            android:checked="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/seperator"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taque"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="Question"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:typeface="normal"/>

                <com.applidium.shutterbug.FetchableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/splash_icon"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/normal"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taOpt5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="0"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:hint="Option 1"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/normal"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taOpt6"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:hint="Option 2"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/normal"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taOpt7"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:hint="Option 3"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/normal"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/taOpt8"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:hint="Option 4"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but after that just one layout is working other is still hidden.

Comment: You can change other height to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` .

Answer (score 0):

Your linear_layout height is fixed at 0 and hence not expandable. use `wrap_content or match_parent.`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Coordinate Layout don't work with API version 25 or less if you are Using these for Application change it Other like Frame,Linear or Relative....
Layout also have Time Complexity i.e for Frame O(1), Linear (n), Relative O(n2)